# Can't alter figsize of a plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using the function described [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/linear_regression_diagnostics_plots.html) to get some diagnostics on multiple linear regressions.

The last code line reads `# Fig and ax can be used to modify axes or plot properties after the fact.`

My code:

```
cls = LRD(lm6_fit)

f,ax = cls();
```

Now, I have tried so many different ways to change the size of the figure but nothing worked...

if I run `f?` I some information about `f`, such as:

```
Type:           Figure
String form:    Figure(1000x1000)
Attributes
----------
patch
    The `.Rectangle` instance representing the figure background patch.

suppressComposite
    For multiple images, the figure will make composite images
    depending on the renderer option_image_nocomposite function.  If
    *suppressComposite* is a boolean, this will override the renderer.
Init docstring:
Parameters
----------
figsize : 2-tuple of floats, default: :rc:`figure.figsize`
    Figure dimension ``(width, height)`` in inches.
```

But I'm not sure how to modify the parameter `figsize` existing in `f`. I tried `f.set_size_inches(K,L)`, for different values of `K` and `L`, but nothing changes.

Comment: if you're working with IPython inline backend, you'll have to show the figure again after changing its size (`display(f)` or just `f` as last line in a cell), the already shown figure will not be changed

Comment: What do you mean by "IPython inline backend"? Is it the `%matplotlib inline` command?

Comment: yes, sorry for being a bit unclear here; see also [this note](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/interactive.html?highlight=ipython#jupyter-notebooks-jupyterlab)